# Use a boolean Asp ControlParameter in a EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Hi I have this EntityDataSource bound to a ListView

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource_utenti" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=db_shieldtrustEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="db_shieldtrustEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="utenti" Include="elenco_utenti" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" Where="" EntityTypeFilter="" Select="">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_tipo_utente" Name="tipo_utente" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_abilitazione" Name="ablitato" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Boolean" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

The second ControlParameter is referred to a DropDownlist, definied in this way

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_abilitazione" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```

and filled in the page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {                
            //databinding della ddl dell'abilitazione utente
            DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Abilitazione-", ""));
            DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Abilitato","1"));
            DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Disabilitato", "0"));
        }

    }
```

but when I change an Item in the DDL I obtain this error: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings "1" and "0" are not valid `Boolean` values. Use "True" and "False" instead.

```
DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Abilitazione-", ""));
DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Abilitato","True"));
DropDownList_abilitazione.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Disabilitato", "False"));
```